# Changing one CLJC-file causes full recompile

Tags: clojurescript

In a fairly large project I am working on, I have a separate source folder with .CLJC-files that are shared between the frontend (Clojurescript) and backend (Clojure).

I noticed that making a trivial change in a CLJC file (e.g., adding a blankline) causes all or most of the CLJC + Clojurescript files to be rebuilt (as listed by the compiler with :verbose to true). This causes a delay of about 45 seconds on my machine. Strange thing is that this even happens when the CLJC does not contain any functions, and is not require'd by any other CLJS/CLJC file...

Does anybody know what could cause this behaviour? My project file is quite standard, and I use the latest versions (CLJS 1.9.293, lein-cljsbuild 1.1.5 or even 1.1.6-SNAPSHOT).

Unfortunately it is not possible to even temporarily remove those pecularities from the project just to test this issue.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question:

This problem was not caused by the specifics of my project -- it happens with every project, because it may be the case that a CLJ or CLJC file contains macros that (when changed) cause CLJS files to be implicitly modified. lein-cljsbuild therefore recompiles all CLJS files.

For some background discussion, see https://github.com/emezeske/lein-cljsbuild/issues/345

I have filed a bug report at https://github.com/emezeske/lein-cljsbuild/issues/457

Comment: And for those using Figwheel: just add ":reload-clj-files {:clj true :cljc false}" to your project file.